# How can I get the active window in a tab?

Tags: vimscript, vim-windows, tabbed-user-interface

For example, if I do:

```
% vim file
:tabedit one
:split two
```

I end up with two tabs, and one tab with two windows.

How can I get the active window of the second tab? My goal is to get a list of all tabs with the currently active window/buffer, and should work in any context (i.e. not just when that tab is active).

Answer (score 3):

The `tabpagewinnr()` can be used for this; for example:

```
:echo gettabinfo()
[{'windows': [1000],       'variables': {}, 'tabnr': 1},
 {'windows': [1002, 1001], 'variables': {}, 'tabnr': 2}]

:echo tabpagewinnr(1)
1
:echo tabpagewinnr(2)
1
```

In this case, the first window is active in both tabs; the "winnr" is scoped to a current tab and starts at 1, whereas the "window id" is global and starts at 1000. To transform a winnr to a windows ID you can use `win_getid()`:

```
:echo tabpagewinnr(1)->win_getid(1)
1000
:echo tabpagewinnr(2)->win_getid(2)
1001
```

The argument for `win_getid()` is the tabnr; by default it will look up the winnr in the current tab so you need to specify it again.

For example to print all tabnrs with the currently active window's buffer name:

```
for t in gettabinfo()
    let w = tabpagewinnr(t.tabnr)->win_getid(t.tabnr)->getwininfo()[0]
    echo printf('%-4d %s', t.tabnr, bufname(w.bufnr))
endfor
```

Which should print something like:

```
1    file
2    two
```

Answer (score 2):

In Vim the tabs are always numbered from 1 to `tabpagenr("$")`.

Also, `gettabinfo()` returns window list ordered by winnr.

Given that, we are able to rewrite our logic like this

```
echo range(1, tabpagenr("$"))->map('tabpagewinnr(v:val)->win_getid(v:val)')
```

Or, alternatively,

```
echo gettabinfo()->map('v:val.windows[tabpagewinnr(v:key + 1) - 1]')
```

Both should produce list of active winids ordered by tab number.